# PHP send form to email - display content on next page

Tags: php, email, session

I'm having some issues with getting the form content sent to email and saved to a session and then displayed on next page.

I have form on contact.shtml which action takes it to mail.php and when content are sent goes to thank_you.shtml.
I need the content shown on the thank_you -page.

All my pages are *.shtml - are this an disadvantage for this?

Codesnippets:
mail.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
```

thank_you:

```
<?php
echo "Navn:" . "$_SESSION['name']";
echo "Email:" . "$_SESSION['email']";
echo "Telefon:" . "$_SESSION['phone']";
?>
```

I have the obvious on page thank_you and mail.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Beside these few lines i have several more with text input and also image files for which i want to show the filename and extensions and also a small preview.
Am i missing something or on the complete wrong track?

Comment: remove the `"` here: `echo "Navn:" . $_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: and have you added `*.shtml` to be parsed as php in your server-config?

Comment: You do know that not filtering output assures you'll have a XSS vulnerability ?  At least add htmlentities() around the string on output. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: @Jeff, if you think of php.ini, then i have no access to it... Are there a workaround or?

Comment: @swa66, are now added :) Thanks a lot - it's hard to figure out how to create secure scripts.

Comment: Define: 'some issues'.

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass using a session.  While I like separation of concerns the following outline 'all-in-one' solution would satisfy your problem:

```
<?php
$email = null;
$sent  = false;
$error = null;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
    if($email && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // supplied email looks good, send email here.
        $sent = true;
    } else {
        $error = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
    }
}
?>
html goes here..
<?php if($sent) { 
    echo 'Thankyou. The email you supplied is: ' . htmlspecialchars($email);
?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo $error ? '<p>' . $error . '</p>' : ''; ?>
    <form method="POST">
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email) ?>">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

If a valid email is posted, you can then trigger your mail out.

Do you really need to display the gathered user data?

Comment: Yes i want to show the gathered data that the user have sent. This should be stored in a session that stops when the user goes further than thank_you.shtml.

Comment: As above, no session required. (For simple small forms at least.)  You have no way of knowing that the user has left the thank you page.

Comment: I have a large form containing also fileupload. I believe that when the user comes to the thank you page the usercontent can be shown and the session can be stopped?

Comment: 'Comes to' is different to 'further'.  But yes, you could clear the session vars there.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo "Navn:" . htmlentities($_SESSION['name']);
echo "Email:" . htmlentities($_SESSION['email']);
echo "Telefon:" . htmlentities($_SESSION['phone']);
?>
```

You have to remove the quotes around the variables. Use htmlentities to convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

Comment: Maybe a few words explanation would make it an answer.

Comment: How about adding htmlentities() around the variable parts that come straight from the user ...

Comment: Ok, I add this one too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have changed to your script now and nothing are shown on thank_you.shtml.

Comment: if "Navn:" and other fixed sentences are not shown, it's not a problem of my code.

Comment: While quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax.  This is only a partial correction/answer to the fuzzy question.